# Possible error in schematic; unrealistic capacitor

Tags: capacitor, schematics

I am trying to get the parts for this [electromagnetic coilgun](http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/electromagnetic_coil_launcher_project), and I have gotten almost all of the parts. I cannot seem to find the 1,000 uF 1.5KV capacitors (C3 and C4) for the voltage ladder, and from my experience with electronics (and a little research) this is a ridiculous value. From the picture in the above link, it  looks like a ceramic cap, but I don't know what it is. Is it a typo? If so, what do you think the right value is?

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: All of the other caps are clearly marked in uF, but those two are listed as 1000M, so I'm pretty sure they aren't uF. I'd guess pF.

Comment: judging by the size I'd bet the same, some mouser parts for ref: http://bit.ly/22gEDYv

Comment: Was this a typo? I don't understand why 1000MF would be picofarads.

Comment: That link doesn't go to a schematic.  This is yet another good example of why all pertinent information to a question needs to be in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of Googling finds [this page](http://www.thinkbotics.com/military.htm), which has the following correction:

> Capacitors C3 and C4
>
> Note that there was a typo for the values of capacitors C3 and C4. The
>   correct values for C3 and C4 are .01uf at 1.5KV DC or higher, ceramic
>   disc.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this schematic.  Regardless of what the marked value in the original schematic means, the correct part has an entirely different value.

Answer (score 2):

M is possibly an abbreviation of micro-micro farad.

A micro-micro farad would be a pico farad.

[See here for a discussion of micro-micro farads.](http://www.eham.net/ehamforum/smf/index.php?topic=46179.0;wap2)

---

This answer is possibly the correct explanation of the marked values for C3 and C4, but is probably irrelevant, as RJR has found the correct values for the schematic in a later article that mentions that the schematic was marked incorrectly.  The correct value doesn't match any reasonable interpretation of the values marked in the original schematic.

I'll leave this here as info on capacitor value markings, but please direct all upvotes to [RJR's answer.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/227125/47070)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a ridiculous value. A 1000µF capacitor, rated for 1500v, would be very large, very heavy, and very dangerous. A 1000MF of the same rating? As big as a house, or more.

As the others have hinted to, the small size of the component dictates that it must be much, much smaller in capacitance. 1000pF sounds reasonable. It could be a translation, typesetting, proofreader, or even intentional error.

The Cockroft-Walton voltage multiplier stage will work just fine with 1000pF caps. It would work *better* with a larger value, but then things get bulky and heavy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a picture of the finished vero board in the link. The 2 x 1,5kV capacitors can be clearly seen - 2 small blue devices. Obviously not 1000uF.